# VBA References Library

Tags: vba, httprequest

I have a macro that is used in my company that creates something called Requests

```
Dim request As New Requests
```

I am creating a new macro with the same standard; however, I can't seem to get it to work. I always get the error below when I attempt to run it.

[image: Error Message]

The following are the References that I have selected.

[image: Selected References]

Comment: I guest the variable is obselete, maybe you need find the latest variable type, especially what is the purpose for the variable request?

Answer (score 2):

The reason selecting all the references isn't working is because `Requests` is user defined.  So there is a missing module, class module or the type hasn't been declared.  More code would help determine the issue specifically.

Comment: @zimide82 A screenshot of the project explorer window would be enough to tell if the class module has been properly defined.

Comment: Correct. Sometimes, renaming a class module will give you the above error and it does not go away unfortunately.